# Water leak on city side increases when house side is on

Tags: plumbing, water, leak

So our home started overflowing from the water meter box. Utility dept comes and says the leak is on the private property side. They back this up by showing how our bill has significantly increased in the past month. Then they shut the service valve off for us, and sure enough the overflowing subsides.  I pump out the water and get to finding the leak. I removed the meter box and lo and behold there is a leak coming from the street side; at least a couple of feet before the water meter. The interesting thing, and my actual question is that while the water to the house is off the leak is pretty slow, but as soon as I turn on the water to our house, that leak becomes a gusher. How can this be? I realize I may have another some other leak causing the bill to go up, but I’m interested in how that leak is increasing and decreasing when the valve is on or off.

[image: hole where leak is coming from]
[image: meter with puddle coming before]

Update: crip659 had it exactly right when he said it was backwards… as it turns out when this house was built they plumbed the pipes in such a way that the meter had to be installed backwards. Makes zero sense they would do that, but alas, it is what it is! So now we do have to do the digging since it is on our side of the meter (plumbing-wise). Thanks to all for your input!

Comment: With the valve turned off, the pressure inside the leaking pipe should be at the greatest= big leaking and should go down some when water is running/being used.  Yours seem to have it working backwards.  Can you post pictures of the leak and location of the valve/meter.  The meter should not be reading water leaking before it.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing which is why I’m a little perplexed.  I added a couple of pictures. The first essentially shows a hole where the water is coming from. I can stick my entire forearm in there and still am unable to pinpoint where the leak is coming from. Don’t want to dig any since it’s underneath the sidewalk. Second pic shows the last section of the meter box that I left there and how it’s essentially dry in there.

Comment: Forgot to mention that there is NOT a sprinkler system, so can’t be that.

Comment: Do you actually see _the pipe_ leaking on the utility side, or do you merely see water rising from the soil on that side? Water can travel underground in surprising ways; the simplest explanation is that water from your side travels and rises on their side. Fix the leak on your side and then check whether the leak "on their side" mysteriously dries up.

Comment: Good point. I don’t actually see the pipe since I don’t want to dig farther  under the sidewalk.  City guts should be coming out soon. We’ll see what they say.

Comment: Where is the actual *property line* in relation to the prospective leak?

Comment: Where we live the city will take care of anything their side of the meter regardless of property line.